# Google map with API key not allowing marker change

Tags: lightning-web-components, api, google-map, lightning-map

I'm currentlly working on a LWC to open up a google map. This map receives some coordinates that come from another integration, and then the final user has to be able to move the marker to the exact position if needed. But that's not the case currently. I can load the map, pass the initial marker values, and render it just fine, but I can't move the marker anywhere else.

I've googled it, tried many options I found there, but none seem to do the trick, I don't know if anyone here could help me. Here are the codes, I've only removed the API key for security reasons. Thank you.

```
<template>
    <!-- lightning button for open modal window -->
    <lightning-button-icon icon-name="action:info" size="small" alternative-text="ArcGis" onclick={openModal} class="toolip" variant="bare"></lightning-button-icon>
    
    <!--Use template if:true to display/hide popup based on isModalOpen value--> 
    <template if:true={isModalOpen}>
        <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC starts here -->
        <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC header here -->
                <header class="slds-modal__header">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                            alternative-text="close"
                            variant="inverse"
                            size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cerrar</span>
                    </button>
                    <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Por favor, ajuste y verifique la ubicación</h2>
                </header>
                <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC body starts here -->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                    <div if:true={isLoading} style="height: 200px; position:relative">
                        <lightning-spinner variant="base" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
                    </div>
                    <div if:false={isLoading} style="height: 300px; position:relative">
                        <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers} zoom-level={zoomLevel} onmarkerselect={handleMarkerSelect} onmaprendered={handleMapRendered}></lightning-map>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Modal/Popup Box LWC footer starts here -->
                <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleSave} title="OK">Guardar</button>
                </footer>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
    </template>
</template>

import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import getGeolocation from "@salesforce/apex/geoLWC.getGeolocation";

const GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY_HERE&libraries=places';

export default class ModalMapas extends LightningElement {
    @api caseId;
    @api open;
    @track isLoading;
    @track isModalOpen;

    map;
    marker;

    mapMarkers = [
        {
            location: {
                Latitude: '9.9356277',
                Longitude: '-84.154545',
            },
        },
    ];
    zoomLevel = 6;
    @track selectedMarkerValue;

    connectedCallback() {
        if (this.open) {
            this.openModal();
        }
    }

    loadGoogleMapsScript(callback) {
        loadScript(this, GOOGLE_MAPS_API_URL)
        .then(() => {
            callback();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading Google Maps API script', error);
        });
    }

    handleMapRendered(event) {
        this.map = event.detail.map;
        this.configureGoogleMap();
    }

    configureGoogleMap() {
        // Access the Google Maps Marker object
        this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: { lat: parseFloat(this.mapMarkers[0].location.Latitude), lng: parseFloat(this.mapMarkers[0].location.Longitude) },
            map: this.map,
            draggable: true
        });

        // Add an event listener for the dragend event on the marker
        this.marker.addListener('dragend', () => {
            this.handleMarkerDragEnd(this.marker.getPosition().lat(), this.marker.getPosition().lng());
        });
    }

    handleMarkerDragEnd(lat, lng) {
        // Handle the marker drag end event, you can update your logic here
        console.log('Marker dragged to:', lat, lng);
    }

    openModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = true;
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.callApexMethod();
    }

    callApexMethod() {
        getGeolocation({ caseId: this.caseId })
        .then((results) => {
            console.log('Respuesta: ' + JSON.stringify(results));
            if (results.Latitud == 'NO' || results.Longitud == 'NO') {
                this.mapMarkers = [...this.mapMarkers]
            } else {
                this.mapMarkers = [
                    {
                        location: {
                            Latitude: results.Latitud,
                            Longitude: results.Longitud,
                        },
                    },
                ];
            }
            this.initMap();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error is ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error.status == '500') {
                this.mapMarkers = this.mapMarkers;
            }
        });
    }

    initMap() {
        this.isLoading = false;
    }

    handleMarkerSelect(event) {
        this.selectedMarkerValue = event.target.selectedMarkerValue;
        console.log('click? ' + this.selectedMarkerValue);
    }

    closeModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }

    handleSave() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
        console.log('nueva ubicacion: ' + this.selectedMarkerValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I assume correctly that the handler `handleMapRendered` is never called? I don't see any `onmaprendered` in Salesforce's lightning-map api. On the other hand I see in Salesforce's map.js under the comment "Handle messages from the child iframe" a single event handled ("markerselect"). What gives you confidence that you can load Google's map Javascript and apply it on the Google map that is encapsulated in Salesforce's web component?